# Remover "Copyright" de resposta com código que não é uma biblioteca de verdade?

Tags: debate, comportamento, novos-usuários

O autor postou isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26386/3635 ao meu ver o código é mais um método de se fazer algo do que uma biblioteca e devido a outras postagens dele, está me parecendo uma propaganda disfarçada:

```
//
//  Constants.h
//  
//
//  Created by William Monteiro on 22/05/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 wmonteiro.net.br. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView ()

@end
```

Fora que nesta postagem ele colocou o e-mail dele https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/77540/1

O que é isso oportunismo? Devemos remover estes tipos "copyrights"?

Comment: Imagino que alguém possa dar uma resposta detalhada embasada nos termos de uso, mas não vejo porque deixar este tipo de informação. Se foi retirado de algum lugar específico, devemos sim dar a fonte, mesmo que de nós mesmos. Mas colocar "fui eu que fiz" num site colaborativo é sem sentido.

Comment: Está resolvido.

Comment: @bigown Realmente a melhor solução, não o fiz por receio de algum conflito, obrigado.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aquele aviso de *copyright* (possivelmente inserido automaticamente por uma IDE) conflitava diretamente com a licença *copyleft* que o site impõe aos conteúdos postados pelos usuários.

Eu acho que caberia ao autor remover o aviso ou a resposta, a seu critério. Mas como o aviso foi removido por outro usuário e o autor (que foi notificado da edição) não reverteu, podemos considerar que ele aceitou postar o conteúdo com a licença que o site impõe.

Comment: Quando ele postou no site ele aceitou os termos do site :)

Comment: Exato, ele aceitou o termo. Mas aviso de copyright dele não _conflita_ com os termos, os termos do site simplesmente invalidam esse aviso.

Answer (score 5):

O copyright postado não tem valor, uma vez os termos de uso do **site o invalidam**.

Agora, acho errado remover a clausula postada por outra pessoa, especialmente relativa a direitos autorais.

Se essa clausula conflita com os termos do site (acho que não pelo fator direitos autorais, mas porque é auto-divulgação), acho que a atitude correta seria remover a resposta, ou pelo menos o código.

Posso estar errado, mas eu **nunca removeria uma clausula de direito autoral** de qualquer coisa, a não ser que eu fosse o proprietário dos direitos.

Comment: Entendo seu ponto de vista, no entanto vale dar atenção ao que foi dito aqui na pergunta do META: *"ao meu ver o código é mais um método de se fazer algo do que uma biblioteca"*... Quero dizer que o código é praticamente padrão e pode ter certeza que nunca removerei copyrights de códigos que são bibliotecas reais. Este código dele é apenas um código "padrão" de interface.

Comment: Ah sim, eu concordo que, além de não poder postar licensas próprias aqui, ele nem tem direito sobre esse código, pela pequena abrangência. Duplamente errado... Mas acho errado remover a clausula _mesmo assim_. Esse assunto é importante porque pode (vai) acontecer novamente.

Comment: É isto mesmo o que quero dizer, se o código é "abrangente", então por mim deve remover sim, mas se for um código relevante, então talvez o melhor seja não remover. Como o caso citado na pergunta do meta foi códigos abrangentes então pra mim foi a melhor saída sim. Note que se o AP discorda ele pode fazer o rollback a qualquer momento, como foi citado pelo @bigown, como o AP não fez o rollback significa que ele concorda... Esse é o motivo que eu gosto dos sites da SE, tudo que é feito (fechar, negativar, editar) pode ser desfeito (desde que seja bom pra comunidade) :)